# Why the drivative of the parametric eqution is dy/dx？

Tags: calculus

For a gerenal fuctions $y=f(x)$, $dy=f'(x)dx$. Thus, we can refer to the derivative of this fuction as $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

For this parametric eqution $ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}y=y(t)\\x=x(t)\end{array} \right.$ , $dy=y'(t)dt$  and $dx = x'(t)dx $. Why are $\frac {dy}{dx}$ the derivative of this parametric eqution？

Can I proof that derivative with $$lim_{t\to0}\frac{y(t+t_0)-y(t_0)}{x(t+t_0)-x(t_0)}=lim_{t {\to} 0} {\frac{\frac{y(t+t_0)-y(t_0)}{dt}}{\frac{x(t+t_0)-x(t_0)}{dt}}}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$ or
$$
lim_{t\to0}\frac{y(t+t_0)-y(t_0)}{x(t+t_0)-x(t_0)}=lim_{t \to 0}\frac{y'(t)dt+\alpha(t)dt}{x'(t)dt+\alpha(t)dt}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}
$$?

Comment: It is a simple application of the chain rule. In general,
$\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$.
Since $\frac{dt}{dx} = \Big(\frac{dx}{dt}\Big)^{-1}$, you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks！！Can I proof that with $lim_{t\to0}\frac{y(t+t_0)-y(t_0)}{x(t+t_0)-x(t_0)}=lim_{t {\to} 0} {\frac{\frac{y(t+t_0)-y(t_0)}{dt}}{\frac{x(t+t_0)-x(t_0)}{dt}}}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$？

Comment: (1) "proof" is a noun. The corresponding verb is to "prove". So you cannot "proof" something any more than you can "hat" your head. (2) the derivative of $(x(t), y(t))$ is $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}\right)$. It is not $\frac{dy}{dx}$. There are situations where one might want to calculate $\frac{dy}{dx}$, which gives the slope of the tangent line to the curve, but it is wrong to call it the "derivative of the parametric equation".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dow konw why we can caculate $dy/dx$ for that curve with chain rule. For $y=sin(t) x=cos(t)$,it’s graph is whole circle.We can get the inverse function $y=sin(arccos(t))$，but it's graph is a semicircle!